# Copying 1KB Byte array to single variables using memcpy. Looking for smarter way

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

I have a byte array `arr` of size 1024 and 4 variables into which I want to copy the beginning of array `arr`.
Later I want to read more data from the array. What would be the best and most dynamic way to achieve this? At the moment I am just copying bytes statically. Maybe a pointer that is set to the current reading position automatically?
Thanks!

```
unsigned char arr[1024];
unsigned char field1 = 0;
unsigned int field2 =0;
unsigned int field3 = 0;
unsigned char field4 = 0;

memcpy(&field1, arr,    sizeof(field1));
memcpy(&field2, arr[1], sizeof(field2));
memcpy(&field3, arr[5], sizeof(field3));
memcpy(&field4, arr[9], sizeof(field4));
```

Comment: Are you so constrained in regards to memory that you absolutely need a char array and basically reinterpret multiple bytes as int?

Comment: Typo (I guess): `arr[1]` should be `&arr[1]` or `arr + 1` (and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
  char *curr = arr; 

  memcpy(&field1, curr,    sizeof(field1));
  curr += sizeof(field1); 
  memcpy(&field2, curr, sizeof(field2));
  curr += sizeof(field2); 
  ...
```

Of course, you could go a step further and make a table:

```
struct Table
{
     void    *field;
     size_t   size;
} table = 
{
     { &field1, sizeof(field1) }, 
     { &filed2, sizeof(field2) }, 
      ... 
 };

 curr = arr;
 for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(table)/sizeof(table[0]); i++)
 {
     memcpy(table[i].field, curr, table[i].size);
     curr += table[i].size;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct:

```
struct s{
   unsigned char field1;
   unsigned int field2;
   unsigned int field3;
   unsigned char field4;
}__attribute__((packed));
```

And then:

```
struct s* ptr;
ptr = arr;
```

That will interpret data from array as this structure. Then just increment pointer if you want to read next records. Please note that I'm using custom GCC extension, look for extension for your compiler if you're not using GCC.

Comment: This does assume that the processor this is running on is happy to read integer fields that are unaligned... And that using the data "in situ" works well.

Comment: `__attribute__((packed))` ensures that structure fields align on one-byte boundaries, so that does the trick.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work if you have an ARM or PowerPC processor, which traps if you access an `int` whose address is not aligned to a 4 byte boundary. And even on x86, which does cope with unaligned accesses, performance isn't great, although it will work.

Comment: I'm not sure that it traps: AFAICT a `packed int` is not an integer in CPU terms, and is not accessed via an aligned 32 bits load. Instead  GCC will generate the alignment adjustment. The x86 saves a bit of code space by doing that same adjustment automatically.

Answer (score 0):

How about a variadic template function to help out.

```
size_t copy_array_r (const void *, size_t, size_t accum) {
    return accum;
}

template <typename T, typename... Params>
size_t copy_array_r (const void *arr, size_t sz, size_t accum,
                   T &arg, Params... parameters) {
    if (sz < sizeof(T)) {
        return copy_array_r(0, 0, accum + sizeof(T), parameters...);
    }
    const char *arrp = static_cast<const char *>(arr);
    std::copy(arrp, arrp + sizeof(T), &arg);
    return copy_array_r(arrp + sizeof(T), sz - sizeof(T), accum + sizeof(T),
                        parameters...);
}

template <typename... Params>
size_t copy_array (const void *arr, size_t sz, Params... parameters) {
    size_t bytes_copied = copy_array_r(arr, sz, 0, parameters...);
    if (bytes_copied > sz) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("insufficient size");
    }
    return bytes_copied;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
bytes_copied = copy_array(arr, sizeof(arr), field1, field2, field3, field4);
```

Answer (score 0):

My take:

```
unsigned int copy_data( void* from, unsigned int size, void* to )
{
   memcpy( from, to, size);
   return size;
}

unsigned int offset = 0;
unsigned char arr[1024];
unsigned char field1 = 0;
unsigned int field2 =0;
unsigned int field3 = 0;
unsigned char field4 = 0;

offset += copy_data( arr + offset, &field1, sizeof(field1) );
offset += copy_data( arr + offset, &field2, sizeof(field2) );
offset += copy_data( arr + offset, &field3, sizeof(field3) );
offset += copy_data( arr + offset, &field4, sizeof(field4) );
```

Then offset is ready to be used for the next read from your buffer.

You can MACROize if you feel (but that's becoming ugly):

```
#define COPY_TO_FIELD( arr, off, field_number ) \ 
 (offset) += copy_data( (arr) + (offset), &field##field_number, sizeof(field##field_number))

COPY_TO_FIELD( arr, offset, 1);
COPY_TO_FIELD( arr, offset, 2);
COPY_TO_FIELD( arr, offset, 3);
COPY_TO_FIELD( arr, offset, 4);
```

Answer (score -1):

Group up your variables in a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char f1;
    unsigned int  f2, f3;
    unsigned char f4;
} __attribute__((packed)) mystruct_t;

unsigned char buffer[1024];
/* Track your position in the buffer: */
unsigned char *pos = buffer;

/* Map your variables on the buffer: */
mystruct_t *first_tuple = (mystruct_t *) pos;
/* Advance your position in the buffer: */
pos += sizeof *first_tuple;
```

Comment: This won't work correctly unless you use GCC extension `__attribute__((packed));` for the structure definition-there will be padding bytes between chars and ints!

Comment: *cough* alignment *cough*

Comment: That assumes that you have no alignment.

Comment: If you're going to use some pragma or __attribute__((packed)), you may as well unionise the thing and avoid the copying.

Comment: @MartinJames: What do you mean by that?

Comment: He probably means to create union with one field that is `unsigned char arr[1024]` and other that is array of structures.

Comment: That may be more convenient, but doesn't "avoid the copying" (which I can't see, anyways).